# Javascript (ExtendScript) Reg Exp match

Tags: javascript, regex, match, extendscript

I'm working in the Adobe ExtendScript environment (Javascript) trying to match a section from a string, but nothing I try seems to work. Here's an example of the string:

```
Q1: Question 1: this is the first question?

- Answer bit
- Answer bit
- Answer bit

Q2: Question 2: this is the second question?

- Answer bit
- Answer bit
- Answer bit

Q3: Question 3: this is the third question?

- Answer bit
- Answer bit
- Answer bit
```

I want to be able to match an entire question and answer bit, so from 'Qx' until the next instance of Q (or Qx+1).
Every RegExp I try either just gets the question line, or returns `null`.

Any help with a solution MUCH appreciated, I still haven't cracked Reg Exp's yet clearly .

Comment: Please post your failed attempts anyway so we can build on those and tell you where you went wrong. In the meantime: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: This is what I'm trying: Q.*?[\s\S](?=Q) I can dynamically insert the question numbers into the Reg Exp so it would be Q1.*?[\s\S](?=Q2) for example. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You only allow for a single character with `[\s\S]`. Repeating it like `[\s\S]*?` should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with this pattern:

```
/Q\d+: (.+)\n\n([\s\S]+?)(?=\n\nQ\d+:|\n*$)/g
```

Where the question is in the first capture group and answers in the second. The trick to know is that the dot doesn't match newlines, it's why I replace it by [\s\S] when I need newlines.

Comment: Returns null unfortunately. Have been trying the [\s\S] thing and seems to do nothing, can't find any way of flowing over the line breaks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You can use a lookahead at every position to check that the current character does not start a new question. If it doesn't, consume the character and repeat. Also note that `.` does not match line breaks. `[^]` on the other hand matches any character:

```
/^Q\d+:(?:(?!Q\d+:)[^])+/gm
```

Or if you want to capture the question separately,

```
/^Q\d+:\s*(.*)((?:(?!Q\d+:)[^])+)/gm
```

Now the question is in group `1` and the answer is in group `2` (which you can `trim` afterwards).